# Dropdownlist One row contains Two Selectable options

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to implement a dropDownList which, on each row to contain two controls: a Label and a Button, but my problem is that I have no clue how to do that.

Searching on google gave me no usefull results, so I don't know from where to start, or perhaps I don't know what to search. This dropDownList should work as a standard one if user clicks on the label, or rise a different event if the button is clicked.

I know this in not the standard type of question here, but if anyone could help me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are asking like you want a label with button , dropdownlist is a html control how can we add another control in it ?

Comment: I want the ddl to have a button on each row, excepting the normal text in in

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropdownlist is simply a list. then Why you need Button and label in Dropdownlist ?

The **DropDownList**  is a control. So it is not possible to add buttons and label in dropdownlist

If you need to do some activities when dropdownvalue changed then you can use **OnSelectedIndexChanged** . You can use it  like buttonclick event

If button and Label are necessary for you then add them in a different way Use frames, or in OnSelectedIndexChanged event create your buttons and labels

Try this  if you are looking for double options related to dropdownlist then try something like below

**css**

```
 ul.dropdown-menu li{
    width: 500px;
}
ul.dropdown-menu li a.text-left{
    float: left;
    width: 49%;
}
ul.dropdown-menu li a.text-right{
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">big button</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
        <div>
            <a href="#" class="text-left">
                full name must align to left 
             </a>
            <a href="#" class="text-right">
                short name - align to right
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
        <a href="#" class="text-left">left</a>

        <a href="#" class="text-right">right</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
        <a href="#" class="text-left">left</a>

        <a href="#" class="text-right">right</a>
        </div>    
    </li>

    <li>
        <div>
        <a href="#" class="text-left">
            full name must align to left
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="text-right">
            short name - align to right
        </a>
        </div>    
    </li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the ddl to have two options: update a gridView if user clicks left side of a row of the ddl with data for that specific index, which I plan to use the OnSelectedIndexChanged event, and remove data for that specific index when user clicks on right side of the ddl item

Comment: @next_user i am not sure what you are actually trying to do, anyway just go through this link may be it will help you http://jsfiddle.net/W55vP/4/  i think you are trying to do something like this

Comment: let me know if you are looking for that

Comment: yes! that is what i was looking for mainly! But i was speaking of a ddl because it is allready implemented, and I thought it was easier to modify that

Comment: @next_user  Ok if my answer is helpfull then tick it as right answer , then somebody can refer it future

Comment: @next_user edit your question correctly otherwise you got more downvotes